# How to export C function in Emscripten when using CMake

Tags: c, cmake, emscripten, emmake

In [this tutorial](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#interacting-with-code-ccall-cwrap) it shows the following example for exporting C functions

```
./emcc tests/hello_function.cpp -o function.html -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS='["_int_sqrt"]' -s EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS='["ccall", "cwrap"]'
```

I would like to do the same except that I use CMake like this

```
cd bin
emcmake cmake ../src
emmake make
```

What is the canonical way of specifying `-s` in emmake? Should I add it to `CMakeLists.txt` like

```
set(EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS '["_int_sqrt"]')
```

or do something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I figured out so far is that it can be achieved CMake with the following settings

```
# Here you can add -s flag during compiling object files
add_definitions("-s EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS='[\"ccall\",\"cwrap\"]'")
add_definitions("-s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS='[\"ccall\",\"cwrap\"]'")
add_definitions("-s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS='[\"_testInt\"]'")
# Here you can add -s flag during linking
set_target_properties(web_mealy_compiler PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=['ccall','cwrap']")
# Set this if you want to to generate sample html file
set(CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX ".html")
```

Then you should be able to call C functions from javascript as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     
    Module['onRuntimeInitialized'] = function() {
     
        console.log("wasm loaded ");
        
        console.log(Module.ccall); // make sure it's not undefined
        console.log(Module._testInt); // make sure it's not undefined
        console.log(Module._testInt()); // this should work
        console.log( Module.ccall('testInt', // name of C function
            'number', // return type
             [], // argument types
             []) // argument values
        );
    }
</script>
```

And this is my definition of C function:

```
#include <emscripten.h>
EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
int testInt(){
    return 69420;
}
```

Comment: Hi. It's discouraged in modern CMake ot use `add_definitions` as it's affecting all targets, the `target_compile_flags` as suggested above is preferable.
Also, according to [Emscripten QA](https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/FAQ.html#why-do-functions-in-my-c-c-source-code-vanish-when-i-compile-to-javascript-and-or-i-get-no-functions-to-process):
```EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE also exports the function, as if it were on EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS.```

Answer (score 4):

This is the simplest/cleanest way now:

```
target_link_options(target PRIVATE
        -sEXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=['_main','_foo','_bar'])
```

And if you have more -s settings (and you probably will) you can add them within this function call, or you can call target_link_options multiple times, both work. It seems quite accommodating, I haven't needed to escape anything.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into exactly the same issue and even started one on the Emscripten github page (see [here](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/11817)).

What worked for me was to put all the Emscripten specific flags into one long string which I then added with target_compile_options and target_link_options.

```
  set(EMS
      "SHELL:-s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=['_main','_malloc','_int_sqrt'] -s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=['ccall','cwrap']"
  )
  target_compile_options(EmscriptenExample PRIVATE ${EMS})
  target_link_options(EmscriptenExample PRIVATE ${EMS})
```

It's **important** to drop both, double quotes and whitespaces from the list of functions otherwise it won't work. At least with CMake 3.17.3 escaping the double quotes did not work for me.

/edit
For the sake of completeness: Emscripten now allows to remove the whitespace between the -s prefix and the actual flag. This makes it possible to actually use CMake's own target_*_options functions, e.g.:

```
target_link_options(target PRIVATE -sEXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=['_main','_foo','_bar'])
```